# When coding in TypeScript should the generated .js files be committed to git?

Tags: node.js, git, typescript

When using TypeScript to write node.js application, what is the recommended way to deal with generated .js files?

Should I add generated .js files to .gitignore and commit only the .ts files or is it OK to commit both .ts and generated .js files?

Comment: It's up to you. It's more a matter of opinion, and as such the question doesn't really fit on SO. That's why I vote to close it.

Comment: No you shouldn't, the same as minified js, css or any generated files. In git you should commit only **source** files.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, thanks. I'm thinking that if I include generated js in git then I can deploy the app from git without the need to recreate js files during automated deployment. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I strongly feel we should be commit only TS files, the whole objective of transpiling them will be lost. Keeping tsconfig & .ts files in GIT will allow to run transpile them to any module loader, target es5 or es6 etc. If JS files are kept as is in GIT, chances are high that people use it without utilising TS features

Comment: Ideally, the source files should be built and deploy by continuous integration services, such as `codeship`. Why you shouldn't commit build files in git? The simple scenario: you have two environments staging and production, for the first one you need to use non-minified js files (for debugging), for the second one - minified files. If you will generate the files before deploy, it won't be problem. But if you'll commit generated files in git, it will be impossible to deploy to a few envs.

Comment: Besides of this, *any change* of the source file will require to commit two files: source and generated.

Comment: if you have proper deployemnts environemnt and build on deployment server is the same as on your machine (same libraries, same versions etc) then you don't have to commit source files. If your build process is not in the place then it's better to commit those so you are sure that thing you push to the server is the thing you just tested. Another approach is to push compiled code somewhere else (in the main repo keep only source and on top of that create some packages you can easily pick and push to production/staging).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Any** build artifacts for **any and every** VCSes have to be excluded from storing in repository. Just because repository must hold sources, using which you can re-build results in any environment and in any intermediate stored state