# How do we easily solve merge conflicts due to transpiled files in React applications?

Tags: git

Basically, every time I pull from the branch alpha, I get merge conflict from the transpiled file, since when I transpile the code from my local in branch ticket01, the transpiled files from alpha results in merge conflicts and I need to add and remove files manually and it takes like 3-5 minutes to do so, how can I do it in a faster way?

I usually just add and remove files one by one, but it's really time-consuming. I am wondering if there's a faster way to do this.

```
both modified:   shared/index.html
added by us:     shared/main.0082fd352490a6b88fcb.js
added by us:     shared/main.0082fd352490a6b88fcb.js.map
both deleted:    shared/main.39c898886d701455d64f.css
added by them:   shared/main.fe78fcf154793a894619.js
added by them:   shared/main.fe78fcf154793a894619.js.map
added by us:     shared/main.4406f78d4a0c36accd6b.css
both deleted:    shared/main.7e753afe38097d82c66c.js
both deleted:    shared/main.7e753afe38097d82c66c.js.map
added by them:   shared/main.d462fdd60359af1dd226.css
both modified:   views/home/app/shared/index.html
```

I want to get rid of my local changes (added by us) and always override the code in my local when there's a conflict between alpha and my local branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `-X theirs` to your `git pull` or `git merge` command. This would instruct git to use the recursive [merge strategy](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_merge_strategies) with the `theirs` option. It would always favour changes from the branch that is being merged in when there are merge conflicts.

Another option you have is to just run your build script (e.g. `npm run build` or whatever you're using) to recompile your scripts when you get the merge conflicts. Then just add the newly compiled files and continue with the merge. The old ones would probably be deleted by the build script.

Side note: often files like these [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37093846/3486675) [need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796373/3486675) to (and probably shouldn't) be tracked in version control since they can be compiled from the source code. You'll make your life much easier if you can keep them out of your repository. :)